# Navision 5 and COM Interop

Tags: events, com, navision

While trying to understand how Navision 5 can communicate with an external application through COM interop, i found the following example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973247.aspx

The second case implemented is exactly what I want to do. I tested the code (with minor modifications - added some attributes `[ComVisible(true)]` on the events interface and class) and with these modifications it worked as stated in the example.

However, I cannot understand why we do not get an exception on invoking the `COMTimer.Elapsed` through the following.

```
protected virtual void OnElapsed(EventArgs e)
{
  Elapsed();
}
```

Who is hooked to this event? The only "hook" i can see is the `mTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(mTimer_Elapsed);` that refers to the `Elapsed` event of the `mTimer`.

Normally, `Elapsed` would be *null* in the `OnElapsed` function.

I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting problem.

`WithEvents` property on automation creates the handler and attaches it to `Elapsed` delegate, so this one is not `NULL` - hence no exception

However, when `WithEvents` is `No`, and `Timer.Start()` is invoked, as you rightly say no exception bubbles up, even though (in theory) `Elapsed` delegate is null.

The simple explanation to this would be, that NAV attaches empty delegate regardless of `WithEvents` property. To support that, if you put code in `Timer::Elapsed()` trigger, then take off `WithEvents`, and bring it back - the code will still be there (i.e. trigger still exists in unchanged form), which makes me lean towards conclusion that it exists always (i.e. empty delegate).

But of course it's NAV so it couldn't be that simple.

I created a test codeunit from above MSDN example, but made a small change to the automation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Whenever the internal timer elapses, an event must be fired
/// </summary>
private void mTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    OnElapsed(EventArgs.Empty);
    throw null;
}
```

This, in theory, should throw `NULL` whenever `mTimer_Elapsed` is invoked - nothing however bubbles up in NAV. I went a bit further and changed this:

```
///<summary>
/// Invoke the Changed event; called whenever the internal timer elapses
/// </summary>
protected virtual void OnElapsed(EventArgs e)
{
    throw new InvalidCastException("test");
    //Elapsed();
}
```

Again, nothing happens in NAV.

Note, that both changes behave as expected if the `COM Timer` is consumed from within .NET project. This makes me think, that NAV Interop must be capturing exceptions from the automation and handle them internally.

I would however pop that question in [Mibuso](http://mibuso.com/) - someone there will probably know better.

Comment: thank you. Keep in mind that when you call the external procedure (that will raise the event-to-listen) from a codeunit 
(suppose on its OnRun trigger) that is not set as SingleInstance, then when the OnRun() finishes its execution the codeunit "dies" and NAV will never listen to the event risen.  If you want to be able to listen to this event use one of the following methods. Either, set the Codeunit as SingleInstance or put the NAV handler and launch the external procedure in the NAV form that will use the event's information and that stays alive while the external code is running.